# R Plotly: Change colors of plot when color variable is used

Tags: r, r-plotly

I am new to plotly and do not know how to set the colours for the different groups when I use a colour variable. My code looks like this:

```
library(plotly)
a <- runif(10)
b <- runif(10)
c <- sample(c("Group1","Group2"),10,replace = T)
plot_ly(x = a, y = b, color = c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can choose your colors with the `colors` argument.

```
library(plotly)
a <- runif(10)
b <- runif(10)
c <- sample(c("Group1","Group2"),10,replace = T)
plot_ly(x = a, y = b, color = c, colors = c("green","red"))
```

explanation: the "color" argument let's you choose your variables which should be colored and the "colors" argument let's you choose your colors

from help:

> color :
>
> A formula containing a name or expression. Values are scaled and
>   mapped to color codes based on the value of **colors** and alpha. To avoid
>   scaling, wrap with I(), and provide value(s) that can be converted to
>   rgb color codes by grDevices::col2rgb().
>
> colors:
>
> Either a colorbrewer2.org palette name (e.g. "YlOrRd" or "Blues"), or
>   a vector of colors to interpolate in hexadecimal "#RRGGBB" format, or
>   a color interpolation function like colorRamp().